# Can't sanitize select field with WordPress Categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm adding a custom field to page that would select a blog category to feature on that page. All the other fields are working fine, so, i'll post code related only to this field. Getting error 500 when loading page editor.

```
$feat_blog = isset( $values['feat_blog'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['feat_blog'][0] ) : "";
```

This is the field itself

```
<select name="feat_blog" id="feat_blog" value="<?php echo $feat_blog; ?>">
    <?php $categories = get_categories(); foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category->slug ?>"> <?php echo $category->name ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

And sanitization code that's actually causing trouble

```
if ( isset( $_POST['feat_blog'] )){
   $valid_values = array(
            categories = get_categories(); 
            foreach($categories as $category) {
                            echo $category->slug,
            }
   );
    $value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['feat_blog'] );
    if( in_array( $value, $valid_values ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'feat_blog', $value );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things wrong with your code here...

1. You are putting `;` in an array and attempting to assign a variable there.
2. You are `echo`ing in an array.
3. You are running functions inside an array.
4. You are missing the `$` infront of the `$categories` variable.

   ```
   if ( isset( $_POST['feat_blog'] )) {
       $categories = get_categories();
       $valid_values = array();
       foreach($categories as $category) {
           $valid_values[] = $category->slug;
       }

       $value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['feat_blog'] );

       if( in_array( $value, $valid_values ) ) {
           update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'feat_blog', $value );
       }
   }
   ```

What I did here is I moved the `$categories` variable declaration outside of the `foreach` loop and set the `$valid_values` array BEFORE the loop. If you set it inside the loop it is going to reset every time the loop occurs. You also can't use `;` inside of an array as that is intended to close the statement.

Comment: Got it. It sill doesn't save selected value, though